# GCC or Clang Version on Amazon AWS Cloud 9?

Tags: c++, c, amazon-web-services, ide, aws-cloud9

When using Cloud 9 (now owned by Amazon and run as part of their AWS service) as an onlinet IDE for C and C++, and other compiled languages, it seems to create a virtual machine that uses version 4.8.5 of GCC. How do I use a more modern version of GCC, in order to utilize the C11 standard (and C18 revisions) and C++11 (and C++17 revisions) and to better utilize the more comprehensible and more friendly compiler error messages of more recent GCC, and Clang, versions.

How do I "request" or install a more modern version of GCC or possibly use a recent version of Clang as the compiler from within the Cloud 9 AWS instance/virtual machine?

Comment: Just install a modern version of the compiler on your own computer instead of mucking with cloud stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The following command got my Cloud 9 IDE up to gcc version 7.2.1

sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"

gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2)
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.